# Repeated measures with 2 timepoints

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am collecting data where phenotypes are measured at 2 timepoints for multiple individuals.

I know that I can use mixed models with a individual-specific random effect to identify if a phenotype changes over from timepoint 1 to timepoint 2.

What would be an appropriate model to find the change in phenotype 1 associated with an change in phenotype 2?

The type of question I want to answer is: "For an individual who increased their BMI by 1 between timepoints 1 and 2, what is the associated change in insulin levels after adjusting for age and sex?"

Also, if I wanted to adjust for another phenotype, how would I do that?

So, that would be "For an individual who increased their BMI by 1 between timepoints 1 and 2, what is the associated change in insulin levels after adjusting for age, sex, and glucose levels?"